# Toggle terminal buffer vimscript function

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, terminal, terminal-buffer

I'm new to vimscript and writing a function to toggle a terminal buffer. Here is what I tried:

```
let g:toggle_term = "<C-j>"

let g:term_buf_nr = -1
function! ToggleTerminal()
    if g:term_buf_nr == -1
        execute "bot term"
        let g:term_buf_nr = bufnr("$")
    else
        execute "bd! " .g:term_buf_nr
        let g:term_buf_nr = -1
    endif
endfunction

execute "nnoremap ".g:toggle_term ." :call ToggleTerminal()<CR>"
```

The function works fine and toggles the terminal buffer only in case the terminal buffer itself is not focused. If it is focused then pressing the `g:toggle_term` combination does nothing.

Is there a way make `g:toggle_term` to toggle terminal even if the terminal buffer is currently focused?

Comment: Don't you need to also create a `tnoremap` to have the mapping executed? [`:h :tnoremap`](https://neovim.io/doc/user/map.html#%3atnoremap)

Comment: @statox Not sure, because this will send a command to the terminal itself.

Comment: "Not sure" then read `:h Terminal-Job`. `nnoremap` only applies in Terminal-Normal mode.

Comment: @Matt There is no such manual entry. Did you mean `Terminal-mode`?

Comment: @Matt execute `"tnoremap ".g:toggle_term ." exit<CR> :call ToggleTerminal<CR>"` does not really call the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @statox suggested in comments I should have used `tnoremap` to implement it. The following works fine:

```
execute "tnoremap ".g:toggle_term ." <C-w>:call ToggleTerminal()<CR>"
```

---

The mistake I initially made was the space right after the `N`

```
execute "tnoremap ".g:toggle_term ." <C-w>N :call ToggleTerminal()<CR>"
```

and since I rebound leader to `<space>` it did not work the way I wanted.

Also, the declaration

```
let g:term_buf_nr = -1
```

should be script private and replaced with

```
let s:term_buf_nr = -1
```

Comment: No need `N`, there is `:h ctrl-w_:`

Comment: @dedowsdi Could you please expand? There is a manual entry specifying that C-w N is the combination to switch to a normal mode. `:h terminal-use`

Comment: `:h ctrl-w_:` is a valid command in vim, execute it, you should see everything.

Comment: @dedowsdi Really, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I slightly refactored your function and made it more robust. After quitting the terminal, with for example `exit` command in Windows, you will get an error when trying to invoke your `ToggleTerminal()` function.

```
let s:term_buf_nr = -1
function! s:ToggleTerminal() abort
    if s:term_buf_nr == -1
        execute "botright terminal"
        let s:term_buf_nr = bufnr("$")
    else
        try
            execute "bdelete! " . s:term_buf_nr
        catch
            let s:term_buf_nr = -1
            call <SID>ToggleTerminal()
            return
        endtry
        let s:term_buf_nr = -1
    endif
endfunction

nnoremap <silent> <Leader>t :call <SID>ToggleTerminal()<CR>
tnoremap <silent> <Leader>t <C-w>N:call <SID>ToggleTerminal()<CR>
```

By enclosing the `else` part of the code in try-catch block, you can react to the aforementioned problem accordingly. I bet you can also `let s:term_buf_nr` on even of closing the terminal, but I don't know how to do it (I didn't bother, as this solution works for me just fine).

The only thing I don't like about it yet is the fact that it destroys the buffer instead of hiding it somehow, but that's different topic :)

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a robust way to toggle a terminal and ended up building something that meets my expectations.

- Off: any visible terminal is hidden
- On:  terminal as a bottom panel (restore first hidden terminal or create new one)
- Works with already open terminal
- Arguments: size and side of the terminal, defaults to 6 lines at the bottom

It seems pretty robust, but any idea to improve it is welcome.

```
function! PutTermPanel(buf, side, size) abort
  " new term if no buffer
  if a:buf == 0
    term
  else
    execute "sp" bufname(a:buf)
  endif
  " default side if wrong argument
  if stridx("hjklHJKL", a:side) == -1
    execute "wincmd" "J"
  else
    execute "wincmd" a:side
  endif
  " horizontal split resize
  if stridx("jkJK", a:side) >= 0
    if ! a:size > 0
      resize 6
    else
      execute "resize" a:size
    endif
    return
  endif
  " vertical split resize
  if stridx("hlHL", a:side) >= 0
    if ! a:size > 0
      vertical resize 6
    else
      execute "vertical resize" a:size
    endif
  endif
endfunction

function! s:ToggleTerminal(side, size) abort
  let tpbl=[]
  let closed = 0
  let tpbl = tabpagebuflist()
  " hide visible terminals
  for buf in filter(range(1, bufnr('$')), 'bufexists(bufname(v:val)) && index(tpbl, v:val)>=0')
    if getbufvar(buf, '&buftype') ==? 'terminal'
      silent execute bufwinnr(buf) . "hide"
      let closed += 1
    endif
  endfor
  if closed > 0
    return
  endif
  " open first hidden terminal
  for buf in filter(range(1, bufnr('$')), 'bufexists(v:val) && index(tpbl, v:val)<0')
    if getbufvar(buf, '&buftype') ==? 'terminal'
      call PutTermPanel(buf, a:side, a:size)
      return
    endif
  endfor
  " open new terminal
  call PutTermPanel(0, a:side, a:size)
endfunction



nnoremap <silent> yot :call <SID>ToggleTerminal('J', 6)<CR>
```

Comment: That looks great, though for vim (I use Mac) while closing the buffer I need to press an extra key after the mapping to close it. I am using <leader>t to both open and close. Would you know how to get around that? Also terminal opens in again in insert mode, and one needs to press i to actually use it. One more feature that would be handy is to put the focus back in the window from where the terminal was invoked... that's especially true for sessions with many windows/splits. Thanks!

Comment: Hi! Unfortunately I don't have a Mac to test that. Terminals might be handled differently on Linux. Also, check whether your Vim is up to date, as the pre-installed version on Mac can be quite old.
You could try to use `feedkeys()` to input `i`, which should enter 'insert mode'. I know use as [updated version](https://github.com/Biggybi/dotfiles/blob/master/vim/plugin/termtoggle.vim) of this script, which actually uses `feedkeys()` (as a workaround for another problem). If you use it, map it with nmap, e.g. `nmap yot <Plug>(TermToggle)`